# Label forecolor(rgb) by dictionary (string, int [])

Tags: c#, arrays, string, dictionary, int

I'm looking for help and maybe the solution is quite simple but I cannot understand. I've been learning and testing C# lately and my problem now is a simple error I read when I try something I also found online.

My purpose is simple: there are 2 labels on my winform that must change their forecolor depending on their text. The text can be 1 of 18 possibilities (single words; that's not the matter, but I set exactly the 18 different words that could be written in the labels).
So, I searched also online and I found something like creating a Dictionary. What I did is something like

```
Dictionary<string, int[]> word = new Dictionary<string, int[]>()
{
    {"Hello", new int[] {144, 144, 153} },
    {"Bye", new int[] {25, 127, 229} }
};
```

then in a specific instance/event, I wrote

```
label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(word[label1.Text[0]], word[label1.Text[1]], word[label1.Text[2]]);
```

so that if (example) the word in Label1 is "Hello", its forecolor shall RGB with values from above, meaning the 3 int values in the "Hello" key.

I'm using visual studio 2019 (if I must know). The error message states that `label1.text[0]` (that should be a string key to get an int value) is a char value and cannot convert to string. Is there something obvious or basic about winform or labels that prevent this code from work properly? Am I doing something wrong? (of course, yes). What am I missing? I've tried to change a string into an object in the dictionary declare but won't work, I tried also using `label1.text.ToString()[0]` but still won't work.

Thanking you already for your answers to come!

Answer (score 1):

From the Dictionary below you have keys `Hello`, `Bye`, and by that keys, you can reach an array whit rgb;

You have to do like this.

```
var label1Rgb = word[label1.Text];
label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(label1Rgb[0], label1Rgb[1],label1Rgb[2]);
```

Example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ClassEtStruct
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] optionsList = new[] { "Hello", "Bye" };

            Dictionary<string, int[]> word = new Dictionary<string, int[]>()
                {
                    {"Hello", new int[] { 144 /*red*/ , 144 /*green*/, 153 /*blue*/ } },
                    {"Bye", new int[] {25, 127, 229} }
                };

            foreach (var option in optionsList)
            {
                int[] colorSettingFromDictionaary = word[option];
                int red = colorSettingFromDictionaary[0];
                int green = colorSettingFromDictionaary[1];
                int blue = colorSettingFromDictionaary[2];

                Color color = Color.FromArgb(colorSettingFromDictionaary[0], colorSettingFromDictionaary[1], colorSettingFromDictionaary[2]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried just now with the solution proposed by OxQ but not working. It always states that label1Rgb[0] is an int and cannot convert to string. Strange to me, can it be something wrong in how the dictionary is declared? Because, by my logic, labelrgb[0] should be seen as var containing a string (the Key), and if i open a [ to write the 0 it should suggest the next item required (like, when i open FromArgb it suggests required an int for red), but actually when i open the [ to insert the 0 it states no suggestion. Like it doesn't expect a value to be inserted there.

Comment: `label1Rgb` will be an int array, with 3 items

Comment: Ok, so, there's a listbox.

When you select an item, there are 2 labels (just need to understand how to do one, then i can do the second) which get a word as a content.

It depends on the item selected, basically i used a dictionary system to attach a series of "values" to any element that could be inside the listbox. Each element in the list has attached string keys with related string values. 2 of those values go in the labels. So, after this, i'd like to change also their forecolors based on which "word" is written inside.

Comment: I have added an additional example MB it will help to understand

Comment: I understand it would be easier just to state the color, but the one above is just an example, my Dictionary with string keys and int [] values is way longer than that. So, stating a series of *******If ("word") {label.forecolor = X,Y,Z}; else if*******etc. for 20 different words (multiplied for every label) would be a waste and huge waste of code rows. That's why i'm thinking about creating a Dictionary, so for anything i'll want to change color i'll just have to refer to the Dictionary.

Comment: @RobertoDVLeonardo yes, Dictionary is a right choice

Comment: Thank you, had to do just a couple of adjustments but your idea was very good! I still don't know well how to go through these comments (i had to open links on this page to go to the code you posted), but i found your example and it was good! Thank you again very much!

Comment: I would recommend you to create a simple console project and paste my example and do step by step debugging it will help you to understand how   dictionaries works